# Installing Simple Oauth module for authenticating users for sharing resources

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am creating  a website on drupal8 on localhost .I implemented restful services and tested it with the postman using Basic authentication . Now I want to use Simple Oauth authentication  and I enabled the simple_oauth  module  and the tab used for creating tokens is not coming on my admin profile , I am very new to drupal and now I am clueless about how to create token.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is, unfortunately no "Simple" authentication method that is "secure". But this may set you on the correct path. https://www.drupal.org/node/2300493